# Can't get NLog 2.0.1 version from NUGet

Tags: dll, nuget, nlog, servicestack-bsd

In Visual Studio 2010, in Package Manager Console I type:

```
Install-Package NLog -Version 2.0.1
```

And I'm getting **2.0.0** (on disk). On [Codeplex](http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/view/32639) there's no **2.0.1** version. Version **2.0.1** is required for ServiceStack.Logging.NLog because of error:

```
Can't load file 'NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of it dependencies. (Exception HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Version **2.0.1** is also listed on NuGet available packages.

I have replaced `NLog.dll` and `ServiceStack.Logging.NLog.dll` with files from latest [ServiceStack v3 snapshot](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3)  and my program runs fine (ASP .Net4 Web Application) but this is not solution for long time. In ServiceStack snapshot `NLog.dll` is **2.0.0** and `ServiceStack.Logging.NLog.dll` is **1.0.8**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NLog version 2.0.1.1 or 2.0.1.2 from NuGet.

The NLog assembly in those packages has a version of 2.0.1.0